# Docker CentOS - mariadb (exit status 0; expected)

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I'm trying to create dockerfile to build an image for a local development environment but every time I let docker run the image the a DB server (mariadb/mysql) gets exited with a status 0.

```
2017-11-17 08:36:10,854 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2017-11-17 08:36:10,864 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-11-17 08:36:10,865 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2017-11-17 08:36:10,865 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2017-11-17 08:36:11,873 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 9
2017-11-17 08:36:11,876 INFO spawned: 'mariadb' with pid 10
2017-11-17 08:36:12,973 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-11-17 08:36:12,974 INFO success: mariadb entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
**2017-11-17 08:36:13,327 INFO exited: mariadb (exit status 0; expected)**
```

No matter what type of DB server (MariaDB/MySQL) I try to add to the dockerfile its gets exited.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos:centos7
# Install tools 
RUN yum -y install curl wget unzip git vim python-setuptools yum-utils which epel-release

# Install Python and Supervisor 
RUN yum -y install python-setuptools \ && mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor \ && easy_install supervisor

# Install Apache 
RUN yum -y install httpd

# Install Remi Updated PHP 7 
RUN wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm \ && rpm -Uvh remi-release-7.rpm \ && yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70 \ && yum -y install php php-devel php-gd php-pdo php-soap php-xmlrpc php-xml

# Reconfigure Apache 
RUN sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf \ && chown root:apache /var/www/html \ && chmod g+s /var/www/html

# Install MariaDB 
RUN yum -y install mariadb-server

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf 
EXPOSE 80 3306 
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

**supervisord.conf**

```
[unix_http_server]

file=/tmp/supervisor.sock 

[supervisord] nodaemon=true

[program:mariadb] command=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe

[program:httpd] command=/usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

[group:allservices] programs=mariadb,httpd

[rpcinterface:supervisor] supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl] serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock         ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket
```

Comment: Could you show me please `supervisord` config file? Remember you need run database in foreground

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I've just added the supervisord config file. Adding a -DFOREGROUND tot the mariadb command didn't solve it. But I'm not very familiar with supervisord ...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to find a good strategy to debug your MariaDB image.

My solution is to set a temporary CMD in Dockerfile with

```
CMD ["sleep", "999999999999999"]
```

So, you can later launch bash or sh in the started container and launch you MariaDB start binary or your supervisord command.

However, I seriously recommend you to compose a stack separating MariaDB from PHP7, chasing the scenario where each container run a single process (and I know, PHP sucks for this). 
Begin by separating MariaDB from PHP ;)